# sqlclient connection Error, between desktop sqlserver and Win device sqlserver CE

Tags: sqlclient

I have a problem with a **Win device**, i failed to connect to computer database wireless, my goal is to sync data between SQL server on PC and the SQL server CE on the Win device, but the connection failed to established with the following exception: 
- When trying to connect using server Name: "sql server does not exist or access denied" 
- When trying to connect using server IP: success on one computer and failed on another one with this exception "PlatformNotSupportedException"

any help appreciated
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with Alien Hand-Held 9011 which happens when the collation in the database and its columns you're connecting to is "Arabic_CI_AS", apparently this is an issue in the 9011 model but not in 9001!
Once you change the collation to "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" the errors will be fixed.